# Is there any Riemannian manifold of zero dimensional isometry group such that

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-curvature

Sorry if this question is belongs to MSE. I have no idea about it.

> **Question:** Is there any Riemannian manifold of zero dimensional isometry group which its Ricci curvature is positive (or maybe zero)?

I know that due to Joachim Lohkamp every smooth manifold of dimension at least $3$ admits a complete metric whose Ricci curvature is bounded between two negative constants.

Comment: If you take any Ricci-positive metric and perturb the metric just a little in $C^2$, then the resulting metric is still Ricci-positive and generically admits no more isometries. You could change the question, replacing "of zero-dimensional isometry group" by "which does not admit a smooth effective action by a compact Lie group of dimension $\ge 1$". If a manifold $M$ admits a smooth action by a compact Lie group, then there exists a Riemannian metric on $M$ for which the action is isometric.

Comment: @SebastianGoette: A perturbed Ricci-positive metric may  admits no more isometries? really? do you have any concrete example in your mind?

Comment: You can take the following surface in $\mathbb R^3$: $(x^2+y^2+y^2)+10^{-10}(x^3+2y^3+3z^3)=1$.  It's group of isometries is trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I meant of course $(x^2+y^2+z^2)+...$ - a tiny perturbation of the unite sphere

Answer (score 6):

Such a manifold exists (with zero Ricci curvature): the automorphism group of the 3-dimensional flat manifold of Hantzsche and Wendt is finite.

See the book of Charlap: Bieberbach groups and flat manifold.

Comment: Sorry, but i couldn't found that example? (and I don't know how I accepted this answer (maybe I trusted to up-voters))